# Angular 4 Router Causes App to Fail Load

Tags: angular

I have created a test app using Visual Studio 2017, ASP.NET Core, and Angular 4 (4.0.0 and now 4.0.3). Everything is working well except for the routing. I have two anchors with routerLinks (home and test) in the app.component template and these function as expected.

I want to test clicking a button and manually navigating with this.router.navitate, but as soon as I add an import for Router and then constructor(private router: Router) to any component (home), the app shows a static div from index.html and fails to load.  I've also noticed that, if I type a path on the command line like localhost:10043/test I get a 404 error, even though it looks correct when I navigate within the app using the router links. I've tried various browsers with the same result.

I'm not sure how to debug this.  There is nothing in the browser console.

EDIT: I downloaded the default Angular setup and ran it under Node and had no issues with the router.  It seems my issue has to do with running under ASP.NET Core and IIS Express.

Comment: Could you please add that code for redirecting to some state and error as well?

Comment: The code I plan to use is this.router.navigate() but the app freezes on load as soon as I add the constructor with DI of Router to any component.  There is no error.  Just doesn't load.  If I comment out the constructor, the app loads.  Must be down in the Angular code somewhere that it is failing and not giving any error.  If I leave it long enough I sometimes get a message about a long running script.